# make: No rule to make target in Kitkat

Tags: makefile, build

I am working in Android source code with Kitkat version, and I encounter a weird problem when I executing make command, the error message are listed below.

```
make: No rule to make target `out/target/product/msm8909_512/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/revlib_intermediates/export_includes',
needed by `out/target/product/msm8909_512/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/third_party_harfbuzz_ng_harfbuzz_ng_gyp_intermediates/import_includes'.  
Stop.make: Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I can't find a proper answer so far, do I need to install any additional libraries ?

Env: ubuntu 12.04 && java version 1.6.0_45

Please do me a favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
No rule to make target xxx, needed by yyy.
```

This means that make decided it needed to build a target, but then couldn't find any instructions in the makefile on how to do that, either explicit or implicit (including in the default rules database). If you want that file to be built, you will need to add a rule to your makefile describing how that target can be built. Other possible sources of this problem are typos in the makefile (if that filename is wrong) or a corrupted source tree (if that file is not supposed to be built, but rather only a prerequisite).

[reference](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_16.html)

Comment: I have a question, now I can build the same source code successfully in another computer with familiar environment (ubuntu 12.04 && java version 1.6.0_45). This really confused me, I didn't modify any makefile, so I think there are some libraries I didn't install in origin workspace.

Comment: or it could be that you might have had some corrupt files in the origin workspace.

Comment: I found this error message: external/chromium_org/third_party/harfbuzz-ng/src/hb-ot-shape.cc:43:27: fatal error: rev_rendering.h: No such file or directory